# How do I set a request timeout and cache policy in AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm following the given example code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

To change the timeout and cache policy I 'hacked' the library and created

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                          timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval
                    cachePolicy:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy
                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:timeoutInterval];
    [request setCachePolicy:cachePolicy];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

    return operation;
}
```

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: A clean way to the have your own class extend the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager ` and add the method to that class.

Comment: That is indeed a good point... I'll do that for the time being.

Comment: There's no cleaner way. The utility methods are terse and don't include all the parameters that you might want to set.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm a bit lazy to categorize or subclass. You can access the manager's request serializer directly:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = INTERNET_TIMEOUT;
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
```

Answer (score 6):

The best is to create a subclass

(you can also the same way add cache policy)

**TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer.h**

```
#import "AFURLRequestSerialization.h"

@interface TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer : AFHTTPRequestSerializer

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval timeout;

- (id)initWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout;

@end
```

**TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer.m**

```
#import "TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer.h"

@implementation TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer

- (id)initWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.timeout = timeout;
    }
    return self;

}

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                     error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [super requestWithMethod:method URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:error];

    if (self.timeout > 0) {
        [request setTimeoutInterval:self.timeout];
    }
    return request;
}

@end
```

**Use**

```
self.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer = [[TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer alloc] initWithTimeout:30];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a category AFHTTPRequestOperationManager+timeout to add this method without having to subclass AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **Method 1** for a **cleaner way** to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238330/435040

The difference is that I'm using subclassing and I'm not patching AFNetworking's code.

One thing that I forgot to mention. In that answer I'm only changing the timeout interval, but adding some other caching policy is just 1 more line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:kRequestTimout];
```

where `kRequestTimout` is the timeout duration you want

Then build your serialized request :

```
NSURLRequest *serializedRequest = [self.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer requestBySerializingRequest:request withParameters:parameters error:&error];
```

And create & add your request operation :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:serializedRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
[self.requestOperationManager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```