# iOS - Increase timeout for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm downloading JSON data from a very slow server. It takes about a minute to get a resoonse from the server. I use AFNetworking library and my code throws "The request timed out" error:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/account.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",baseUrlString];

    NSString *login = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"login"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];

    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:login password:password];


    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [self parseJsonWithAccountsData:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(failedWithContactsDownload) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
```

Didn't find a way to set a timeout for `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953964/how-do-i-set-a-request-timeout-and-cache-policy-in-afnetworking-2-0 Seems that you can only change the timeout if you extend the GET: method of the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1.**

I think the best way is to subclass `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` and override

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

like this:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [super requestWithMethod:method URLString:URLString parameters:parameters];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:YOUR_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL_HERE];

    return request;
}
```

and then

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/account.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",baseUrlString];

    NSString *login = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"login"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];

    [manager setRequestSerializer:YOUR_NEW_REQUEST_SERIALIZER_HERE];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:login password:password];


    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [self parseJsonWithAccountsData:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(failedWithContactsDownload) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
```

**Method 2**

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/account.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",baseUrlString];

NSString *login = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"login"];
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];

[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:login password:password];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:urlString relativeToURL:manager.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:nil];
[request setTimeoutInterval:YOUR_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL_HERE];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    [self parseJsonWithAccountsData:responseObject];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(failedWithContactsDownload) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I had to override - (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                     error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error also, but your answer is absolutely correct!

Comment: PgmFreek's solution is the way to go with 2.0.

Answer (score 42):

In AFNetworking 2 library there is method in `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` set the request time out interval directly.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/account.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords",baseUrlString];

    NSString *login = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"login"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];

    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:login password:password];
    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:TIME_OUT_INTERVAL];


    [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [self parseJsonWithAccountsData:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(failedWithContactsDownload) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];
```

You don't need to override the class to set the request time out interval.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit lazy to categorize or subclass. You can access the manager's request serializer directly:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = INTERNET_TIMEOUT;
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. While debugging I found out my timeout wasn't respected when set with this method. Only subclassing seems to work as for now.

Comment: Hmm... Tests I've run using AFNetworking 2.5.4 varying the timeout between 1 and 120 seconds all perform fine.

Comment: Hm, that's weird. For me Your solution timeout is always ~60s for AFNetworking 2.5.4, no matter what value I set (using default AFNetworking manager singleton). However thanks for checking, good contribution!

Comment: @Vive it only worked for me when I created a new requestSerializer     `AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];    
manager.requestSerializer = serializer;
// Then execute the above code`

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass

```
self.requestOperationManager.requestSerializer = [[TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer alloc] initWithTimeout:30];
```

**TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer.h**

```
#import "AFURLRequestSerialization.h"

@interface TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer : AFHTTPRequestSerializer

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval timeout;

- (id)initWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout;

@end
```

**TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer.m**

```
#import "TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer.h"

@implementation TimeoutAFHTTPRequestSerializer

- (id)initWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.timeout = timeout;
    }
    return self;

}

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                 URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                     error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [super requestWithMethod:method URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:error];

    if (self.timeout > 0) {
        [request setTimeoutInterval:self.timeout];
    }
    return request;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the value of `timeoutInterval` property is ignored - I've checked by debugging the method `requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:`

I managed to subclass and override the method (Swift)

```
class RequestSerializer: AFHTTPRequestSerializer {

    override func requestWithMethod(method: String!, URLString: String!, parameters:AnyObject!, error: NSErrorPointer) -> NSMutableURLRequest {
            var req = super.requestWithMethod(method, URLString: URLString, parameters: parameters, error: error)
                req.timeoutInterval = self.timeoutInterval
                return req
    }
}
```